# Логика работы CMS

Tags: php, cms

Требуется создать CMS.

**Админка**

- Создание категорий
- Создание постов
- Создание под-доменов

С первыми двумя ясно, а вот как быть с **под-доменами** ? как они должны создаваться на хостинге ? или перенаправлятся через .htaccess ?

Нужно сделать так, чтобы меньше было тело-движений, ввел имя под-домена, нажал создать и он создался.

Но вот логика работы создания не ясна.

Подобная реализация есть в Wordpress (Multisite), нужно создать мини аналог, но без всех наворотов.

Comment: CMS - зло! Не надо этим заниматься.

Comment: Надо, так как требуют, обычную cms, вся проблема в понимании логики создания под-доменов с остальным все ясно.

Comment: Настраиваем веб-сервер так, чтобы все поддомены направлялись на эту CMS, а внутри CMS уже творим чё хотим. Как настроить веб-сервер - зависит от веб-сервера и к CMS не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @webstackoverload по поводу "под-доменов" обычно надо чтобы поддерживались wild субдомены (любой набранный субдомен вел на корень сайта, или другую папку сайта) и там уже дело техники, либо скриптом определять что за субдомен, либо .htaccess и передавать субдомен в get переменной

Comment: Дело в том что нужно как-то проще это сделать это раз, два нужно понять потом сам процесс, к примеру вводим имя саб-домена, нажимать, создать, процесс пошел. На сколько помню в WP копируется база данных - дублируется для каждого нового саб-домена, но на то есть причины, там плагины посты и т д. Как я понимаю это сложный вопрос..